# Cannot permit parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

This is bizarre to me, so I'm just curious if anyone else has run into this:

I've got the following:

```
def credential_params
  params.required(:credential).permit(:name,:agent_ids)
end
```

In my controller create and update actions I'm using mass assignment with the above parameter call...

```
@credential.update_attributes(credential_params)
```

But I still get `Unpermitted parameters: agent_ids`

If I change this to `params.required(:credential).permit!` (ie permit all) of course it works.

I feel like I must be overlooking some obvious gotcha here... anyone know what it might be?

Comment: shouldn't that be `require`?

Comment: @jvnill - after looking at the docs, it should be, but you know what? It works as 'required' too. I wonder if that's a bug or a feature...

Comment: @jvnill: it's a feature, `required` is an alias for `require`, see the source near: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/blob/master/lib/action_controller/parameters.rb#L58

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
params.require(:credential).permit(:name, { :agent_ids => [] })
```

Comment: I think we posted about the same time, but I'll give you the answer since it's not worth any points to me :) Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 5):

Got it.

An array isn't one of the [supported types](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values):

> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric, TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.

Therefore the solution is to specify an array, like so:

```
params.require(:credential).permit(:name, :agent_ids => [])
```

Hope others find this useful.